# Google adsense (onclick event)

Tags: jquery, adsense

I am using Google Adsense and I was curious whether I can track user's IP address when they click on the ad. As I found out - I can't.

I have written a small code, which should record user info into the database when they click on the ad.

**The problem is to trigger onlcik even on Google Ad (I can't do it for some reason)**.

```
<div class="google_add" style="clear: both;">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"></ins>

    <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script>
</div>
```

**My jQuery**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.google_add > ins').click(function() {
        // Ajax request 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: '/script/of/the/tracker.php'     
        });
    });
});
```

This doesn't work and for some reason and click even does not work.

## I tied

### setTimeout()

I tried using *setTimeout()* - maybe Google does not load fully and it cancels all events on their code - did not work as well.

### onclick=""

I tried using *onclick=""* on  of Google - did not work as well.

I don't really know why this problem happens, so please help and tell me if this is possible to do.

## **UPDATE**

This is the jQuery library that allows to do what I was asking - https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery.

SOLVED!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a Google AdSense ad to do a function when clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099878/making-a-google-adsense-ad-to-do-a-function-when-clicked)

Comment: can you add an answer to your question please ? I'm looking for an answer for this exact question.